# Remove header and footer but KEEP all css and js etc for a custom post template?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

On my site have a custom post type with this info. I stored the file in single-{customposttype}.php.

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
<div style="width:500px;">
<?php
$id = get_the_id();
echo do_shortcode( '[skwidget id="' .  $id . '"]' );
?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The skwidget plugin is called correctly and everything seems to work fine.

**But here's the issue:** Everything gets included but I ONLY want the css for the theme, css for the plugin and all relevant css/js for the plugin but I **don't want header and footer-menu(s)** to be shown. How do I achieve that?

If just remove get_header() and get_footer() then the plugin won't work because it needs js/css etc.

I GUESS I could create header html and footer manually but that doesn't seem like a good idea...

Comment: You can create a custom function to be called after your `get_header()` call. You can include `wp_dequeue_script()` and `wp_dequeue_style()` for all the unnecessary scripts and styles.

References:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style

Comment: Ok, but how that help me removing menus?

Comment: Okay. The other way around is remove your header and footer calls and use `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` functions for necessary scripts and styles and get your thing working.

Comment: @RohitPande - It was not that I was looking for but you got me thinking a little differently and I came up with a solution. I've answered my own question in case someone stumble upon on the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

If someone needs something similar, I actually found an answer to my issue and it is to pass arguments to `get_header()` and `get_footer()`.

```
<?php
get_header('customposttype);
?>
<div style="width:500px;">
<?php
$id = get_the_id();
echo do_shortcode( '[skwidget id="' .  $id . '"]' );
?>
</div>
<?php get_footer('customposttype'); ?>
```

and copy `header.php` to `header-{customposttype}.php` and `footer.php` to `footer-{customposttype}.php`

And after that custom modifiy the

```
header-{customposttype}.php
footer-{customposttype}.php
```

after your needs!